# Show label of stacked columns only on hover (and also the previous and next column)

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

So basically I need to show the labels of stacked columns on hover, BUT I also need to show the labels of the previous and following column of the one I'm hovering.

To summarize, if i have A, B, C, D, and E (each with 3 stacked columns), and I hover on C, I should be able to see B, C and D's labels (for all 3 stacked columns) (and tooltip only for C, but that's default, so no need help there).

Any idea how to accomplish that?

This is the generic code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
        }
    }
},
legend: {
    align: 'right',
    x: -30,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadow: false
},
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
});
```

Here's a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/) with the generic stacked column setup working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS and Highcharts events to hide/show that labels, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2549acmt/

Default CSS:

```
.highcharts-stack-labels text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And JS events:

```
function showLabels() {
  var index = this.x,
      labels = document.querySelectorAll(".highcharts-stack-labels text");
  // previous
  if (index > 0) {
    labels[index - 1].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  // current
  labels[index].style.visibility = 'visible';
  // next
  if (labels[index + 1]) {
    labels[index + 1].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
function hideLabels() {
  var index = this.x,
      labels = document.querySelectorAll(".highcharts-stack-labels text");
  if (index > 0) {
    labels[index - 1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  labels[index].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  if (labels[index + 1]) {
    labels[index + 1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

Attaching events:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
        },
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: showLabels,
                mouseOut: hideLabels
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: You, my friend @pawel-fus are amazing :D

I added some more code so the column labels are also hidden and shown on hover, you can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2549acmt/4/) in case this helps anyone else in the future :)

Thank you so much!

Comment: A smoother version of what I needed to accomplish, with a little transition animation can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2549acmt/7/)